# Comment in a JSON Resource file for Node.js and related projects

Tags: javascript, .net, node.js, embedded-resource, resx

There is a RESX file format for managing resources in the .NET world.

I suppose the Javascript world use just simple JSON ([example](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Elemental.JsonResource)).

The disadvantage of this JSON resource file is that it does not support the comment field like RESX file which might be needed for the proofreading process.

Is there any standard JSON format with comment support for Javascript (Node.js) projects?

You can see that the [comment field is for example used in .NET Core project](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/Core/src/Resources.resx).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this npm module for comments in json file [comment-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/comment-json)

```
  {
  // package name
  "name": "comment-json"
}
```